# Any way to limit buffering as videos are loading?

Tags: firefox, youtube

I'm looking for a way to limit the buffering of videos , in youtube when playing a video i don't want it to buffer the video beyond a certain amount of time. i want it to buffer it gradually as time passes forward. i tried to modify the media.cache in about:config section but it has no effect on it.

is the any possible way?

to clarify , I'm using an expensive internet service, that's why I'm looking for this, sometimes i just watch short amount of a video but it downloads lot more than what i wanna watch.

youtube vanced for android has this feature for example, you can define the buffer to be even 1 sec.

Comment: I always thought it made a generous guess based on the data size & its estimate of your line speed. I was unaware it was user-adjustable.

Comment: AFAIK YouTube uses a custom implementation of streaming and manages buffering independently from browser's settings.

Comment: @gronostaj youtube vanced for android has this feature , so thats why i think it must be possible in desktop firefox.

Comment: YouTube Vanced is a dedicated YouTube app on steroids. Firefox is a web browser. It's certainly possible, but someone would have to spend a significant amount of time building and maintaining it. It's likely that nobody did.